# Does ansi C place a limit on the size of a program in memory?

Tags: c, ansi-c

I've been told this, and couldn't find a confirmation or rebuttal on the web. Is this true? If so, which is the limit? Is it usually enforced by compilers?

Comment: I would expect this to be wildly architecture and OS dependent, and not at all something ANSI would care or concern itself with.

Comment: @Joe: so would I, but I would expect the same about, say the [number of extern variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6835718/does-ansi-c-place-a-limit-on-the-number-of-external-variables-in-a-program), or the position of the first different character in a different variable name. In both cases, ansi specifies lower bounds for what a compliant compiler must support (respectively, 4095 and either 31 or 32). Since ANSI cares about these two, it seemed plausible that it could also care about program size.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ANSI C doesn't concern itself with that kind of thing.

There is nothing in §5 *Environment* in the C99 standard that even talks about "loading a program in memory".

The only considerations are what the environment must provide to be conforming with the abstract state machine that is the basis for the language/standard. That doesn't require "loading a program in memory" - code could be spooled from a deck of punch cards.

There are limits expressed on character sets, the *source* code size and complexity and a few other things - but those are mostly lower bounds that a conforming implementation must accept, and relate to the *translation* environment, not the execution environment.

Comment: Indeed, it doesn't even define what the "size of a program" might be.  Objects have sizes.  Other things, such as functions and storage used for overhead for certain operations, are likely to occupy some space *somewhere*, but the language itself provides no concept of what their size might be.

Answer (score 1):

If your executable is too large you may suffer thrashing, but aside from implementation-specific executable formats there isn't any maximum size.