# Does ansi C place a limit on the number of external variables in a program?

Tags: c, ansi-c

By external variable I mean a variable declared with the *extern* modifier (and defined elsewhere in the program).

I've been told of this limitation, and couldn't find a confirmation or rebuttal on the web. Is this true? If so, which is the limit? Is it usually enforced by compilers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is a **minimal** limit that every compiler should support.

In this case, every compiler should be able to support **at least** 4095 external identifiers in one translation unit (but most compilers probably support much more).

Comment: In practise, Visual Studio and GCC store both in expanding lists, so you are bounded only by the amount of memory that the process has, up to a hard limit of ULONG_MAX-1 elements.

Answer (score 8):

The C99 standard specifies several translation limits (5.2.4.1). One of those is :

> 4095 external identifiers in one translation unit

The C89 standard specifies this limit (2.2.4.1) :

> 511 external identifiers in one translation unit

Note that these are minimum limits for conforming implementations, not absolute limits.

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that the language does not impose a maximum limitation.  Compilers and platforms would impose a limit.

Compilers may restict the quantity due to the memory they want to devote to tracking and translating these.

The platform always has limited space for variables.