# Is it undefined behavior to exceed translation limits and are there checker tools to find it?

Tags: c, standards, undefined-behavior, standards-compliance, c89

## ORIGINAL QUESTION:

I'm searching the C90 standard for things to be aware of, when writing hignly portable code, while having low trust in the good will of the compiler vendor, and assuming that my software might kill somebody sometimes, if I do things wrong. Let's say I'm a little paranoid.

At the moment I am thinking about the "Translation limits" (5.2.4.1 ANSI/ISO 9899:1990). As pointed out in the standard and in: "[Does ansi C place a limit on the number of external variables in a program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6835718/does-ansi-c-place-a-limit-on-the-number-of-external-variables-in-a-program/6835870#6835870)", those are minimum requirements for a standard conform implementation. Now on the other hand this means, any implementation does not have to do more - and if I want to be sure that my code works for any confrom implementation, these limits represent absolut limits for me.

So far so annoying.

So the compiler vendor choose limits that equals or are above the minimum required tranlation limits.

What happens now if one exceed these implementation-defined tranlation limits of a specific implementation? In my copy of ANSI/IO 9899:1990 (C90) I haven't found anything, so I think it is Undefined Behavior "of the 3. kind" (by omission). On the other hand would this not be the first time, that I misunderstood the standard or didn't find the right passage.

So here are my questions:

- IS exceeding the translation limits of a specific implementation undefined behavior in C90?
- Does C90 behavior hold for the corrected versions up to C95/C96 and for the new iterations C99 & C11?
- Have anyone seen a checker tool out there, that checks for the minimal, or (tool) user defined limits?

## ASPECTS BEYOND THE ORIGINAL QUESTION:

### Interesting aspects in answers and comments:

1) As [Michael Burr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12711/michael-burr) pointed out in a direct [comment to the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23730590/is-it-undefined-behavior-to-exceed-translation-limits-and-are-there-checker-tool#comment36480076_23730590), according to the C-Standard (I have only checked C90 without corrigendae, and the C99 draft, Michael referenced [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf)) a conform C implementation only needs to accept ONE program, that contains all limits at the same time, which in the strictest interpretation nullifies any minimum limit guarantees.

2) As [rubenvb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/256138/rubenvb) and [Keith Thompson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/827263/keith-thompson) pointed out, implementations of some quality should provide diagnostics for the case, that their implementation defined limits are exceeded, especially if the are not conform to the minimum requirements (rubenvb linked an example for MSVC in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23730590/is-it-undefined-behavior-to-exceed-translation-limits-and-are-there-checker-tool#comment36480626_23730928)).

3) As exceeding the compiler limits might be Undefined behavior, but surely lead to some error, the values of the "variables" to which the translation limits apply for a certain piece of my code represent preconditions for reuse.

### My personal strategies to deal with them

1) So for maximal paranoia, I will make a fool out of myself, and annoy the compiler vendors' support with a request to guarantee me, that the limits chosen by the implementation apply to any program. :-(

2) So I will investigate the compiler documentations and the capacity for suffering of the compiler supports for getting the confirmation, that:
 - that for every translation limit, if being exceeded, a diagnostic will be raised, and
 - because it is undefined behavior, if every instance of exceeding a translation limit will raise a diagnostic - or else another error already prevented a compilation.

3) So I will try to get hands on a tool (or develop myself if I really must), that measure those values, and provide them as precondition for code reuse for my program. As [Keith Thompson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/827263/keith-thompson) pointed out in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23743976/3364914) some of values might need a deeper knowledge on how the Implementation is... implemented. I am not perfectly sure what can help in such cases beyond actions in 2.) yet, as far as I see, I have to test - but I only need to test if there is UB (without a diagnostic), and if this is the case, a successful test can not guarantee correctness in the general case.

## ANSWERED:

Yes it is undefined behavior by obmission.

Keith Thompson has showed in his (accepted) [anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23743976/3364914) with terminology of and reference to the C standard documents, that it is undefined behavior.

A tool that checks transaction limits in the code has not (yet) discovered by the commenters. If a tool occurs to anyone that have (even partly) this functionality, please leave an answer or comment.

Comment: I would guess it is not undefined, but unspecified behaviour.

Comment: AFIAK for unspecified behavior the standard explicitly has to tell you explicitly the aspects, that are unspecified. Please correct me, if I got this wrong - expecially, I only have the old C90 standard at hand.

Comment: Note that strictly speaking (since you seem to be interested in a very strict interpretation), even an implementation that conforms to the minimum translation limits in the standard doesn't *always* have to meet those minimums. The standard says that the implementation has to meet those limits (all of them) only for one program.  Of course, the intent is that the implementation should be able to meet those minimums for any program. But strictly according to the standard, that's not required,

Comment: @MarkA.: you can get a copy of C99 with the TC's incorporated at no cost here: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf

Comment: @Michael Burr. Yes - I struggled with this sentence too. I came to the conclusion, that this (together with the UB I suspect) would render the standard and the compiler useless in total. So I assume the "any"-Interpretation. Thank you though for pointing it out. Thank you for the Link. Anyway I am forced to use C90 atm for production code, with the requirement to be strictly ANSI C90 complaint. But I hope this soon will change - so the C99 standard will help me a lot.

Comment: Please don't modify the answer like you did, people can read the answer by looking at the checkmarked answer below, and please don't extend your question. Instead, ask a new one (or two) and perhaps reference this question.

Comment: @rubenvb Thank you for your remark. I will keep that in mind in future, when asking questions here. Notice however, that I have not extended the question: I have neither changed the question itself nor asked any further - neither related nor not related - questions. Also I have also found answered questions that provided an outline of aspects and the answer most helpful.

Comment: @MarkA.: The authors of the Standard didn't intend for it to describe all of the behaviors that would be expected of a good compiler for any particular platform.  Someone who was particularly obtuse could claim a copy of Rogue was a C implementation which generally a limit of one character per source line, except for lines which happened to match the contents of a copy of Rogue which had a little extra useless code added to test all implementation limits.  Such an implementation would correctly translate the aforementioned copy of the Rogue source, satisfying its requirements...

Comment: @MarkA.: If the documentation indicated that the rogue startup messages were a "diagnostic", then a program which contained only single-character lines (and couldn't possibly be well-formed) would produce a diagnostic as required.  I don't think the requirements to handle `#error` directives are applicable to source files whose input lines exceed an implementation's maximum length, so those obligations would be satisfied.  Of course, any program that outputs anything could be substituted for Rogue, but the intention of the Standard is to describe enough behaviors that non-obtuse...

Comment: ...implementations meeting those requirements will do what's needed in other cases as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the behavior is undefined.

The standard requires a diagnostic for any translation unit that violates a constraint or syntax rule ([N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) 5.1.1.3), and may not successfully translate a translation unit that contains a `#error` directive that survives the preprocessing phase ([n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) 4, paragraph 4). (N1570 is a draft of the C11 standard, but this is the same across C90, C99, and C11, except that `#error` was added by C99.)

All constraints and syntax rules are specified explicitly in the standard. Exceeding an implementation-defined limit violates neither a constraint nor a syntax rule. It's sufficiently obvious, I think, that an implementation is not required to successfully process an otherwise correct program that exceeds a translation limit, but the standard says nothing about how it should respond to such a violation. Therefore, the behavior is undefined by omission.

(An implementation of decent quality would issue a diagnostic saying that a limit has been exceeded, but this is not required by the standard.)

To answer the third part of your question, no, I haven't heard of a static checker tool that checks programs for violations of the minimum translation limits. Such a tool could be quite useful, and probably wouldn't be too difficult to write once you have a C parser. For the limit on the size of an object (32767 bytes in C90, 65535 bytes in C99 and C11), it would have to know how the compiler determines object sizes; `int arr[30000];` may or may not exceed 65535 bytes, depending on `sizeof (int)`. I wouldn't be too surprised if someone has already implemented such a tool and I just haven't heard of it.

Note that most implementations do not impose the fixed limits that the standard permits; rather, any limits are imposed by the memory resources available at compile time.

The standard does present the translation limits in a rather odd way. I'm thinking in particular of the clause that says:

> The implementation shall be able to translate and execute at least one program that
>   contains at least one instance of every one of the following limits:

(that's section 5.2.4.1 in C90, C99, and C11). So a perverse implementation could accept exactly *one* program and reject all others.

The point, I think is that specifying reasonable limits that all implementations must meet would be impractical. The standard could say that all implementations must *always* accept objects of at least 32767 bytes -- but what about a program that defines a million such objects? The limits interact with each other in extremely complex ways, and the nature of the interaction depends on the internal structure of each compiler. (If you think you can define the requirements for translation limits better than the C standard does so, I encourage you to try it.)

Instead, the standard states the requirements in such a way that the easiest way to implement a useful compiler that obeys the *letter* of the standard is to implement a useful compiler that obeys the *spirit* of the standard, by not imposing any unreasonable limits. A useless compiler that meets the letter of the standard is possible but irrelevant; I don't know that anybody has ever implemented such a thing, and I'm sure nobody would attempt to use it.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation. I am fully agree with your argumentation. But I did even before I asked the question. So I will let it stay open for a few days to see, if someone want to present a different view. As for the diagnostics, in some multi-party projects I might have few influence on the choice of the C implementation. Have you heard about a static checker tool checking the translation limits?

Comment: Thank you for the Update. Yes I read those "memory based" up for our compiler. That of course doesn't help to much for the aim of very high compatible code. On the other hand, if I have a checker at hand and/or verify the compiler behavior as part of the development process (and as preconditions for reuse) I might be able to be a little more relaxed on this UB. :-)

Comment: Thank you for the further update. I fully agree, that a compiler that only is compliant to the letter will not be used. And I sure will not say (at least for a couple of years), I could specify anything better then the standard did. (well maybe the "non-empty-file-not-ending-with-new-line-UB-thing...). But I will - and think - have to be pedantic on the interpretation of the standard, especially when it comes to UB, because I am average C-programmer at best, and UB can kill any test procedure finding my (functional) bugs. :-)

Comment: Excellent answer, in fine tune with a very often misunderstood aspect of standard text (and of legal text in general): the difference between the _letter_ and the _spirit_ (or _doctrine_, in law jargon) of the written word. As a side note, ISO C++ includes, for that matter, a statement not found on ISO C: "However, these quantities are only guidelines and do not determine compliance."

Comment: @Alek: The C Standard was never intended to fully describe everything something must do to be a quality C implementation on a given platform, but modern compiler writers have lost sight of that, behaving in ways which--while permissible--would have almost certainly been regarded by the authors of the Standard as obtusely reducing the quality of their implementation.

Answer (score 0):

It's not undefined behavior, it is implementation defined behavior. This means it all depends on the compiler.

Yes, the minimal implementation guidelines remain the same or are extended for newer standards versions.

You probably could use Clang for this, but you'll need to write the tool yourself using the Clang API, I don't know of a pre-existing implementation.

---

In any case: the limits aren't set by the standard, "They're more [like] guidelines anyways", (actually nothing more than guidelines). You'll need to check the compilers you use for building the code to see if you're hitting any limits, no way around that by only waving the standards document in someone's nose. And as MSVC's implementation is particularly sucky, I would even dare to say that if it compiles your code (assuming no illegal constructs are in the code itself), you're pretty safe.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. I can see, that the limit itself is clearly implementation defined. But I can't see the requirment that a compiler to present a diagnostic, or any specified behavior if I exceed the limit. Can you show me the passage in the standard?

Comment: @MarkA. Diagnostics are implementation defined as well, I suppose... At least for MSVC (the only one I hit any limits with), you get descriptive error messages where it tells you why it sucks.

Comment: ANSI/ISO 9899:1990 5.1.1.3 makes the form of the diagnostics implementation defined, and give some "at least"-constraints, in which cases a diagnostics have to presented. Thank you for confirming that MSVC checks for the translation limits. Does it do for C90 ones or for those of newer iterations of the C-Standard? Still it remains unclear for me if in general exceeding the implementation defined limits with my code is undefined behavior.

Comment: @MarkA. MSVC's limits are documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ft39hh4x.aspx) (although lots of C++, there are some C limits in there). It seems now these are just the nonstandard limits, which you are not really looking for... I'll edit my answer.

Comment: How do you conclude that the behavior is implementation-defined? For it to be implementation-defined, there would have to be an explicit requirement in the standard for each implementation to document how it behaves in response to a translation unit that exceeds a translation limit (see the standard's definition of "implementation-defined behavior", 3.4.1 in C11/N1570). Where do you see such a requirement?

Comment: @Keith: examples (C99): `5.2.4.1`, `6.4.2.1/5`, `6.7.5/7`, `6.8.4.2/8`, not strictly "implementation-defined": `7.19.2/8`, `7.19.3/15`, `7.19.4.4/6`, `7.19.6.1/15`, `7.20.2.1/5`, `7.20.4.2/3`, and many more. I agree not all limits (like source file size) are present. I'm sure creative people will always find something that is not specifically stated in the standard. Note I do recommend just to run it on a compiler, as it surely is "implementation-specific" in any case. The standard isn't going to put a hard minimum on translation unit size (it doesn't even have to be a file!).

Comment: @rubenvb: Yes, many of the limits themselves are implementation-defined and therefore must be documented. The question is about the behavior of the implementation when those limits are exceeded.

Answer (score 0):

In some environments, an application may receive stack space equal to the total memory available, minus the combined size of the code and static data.  If the amount of available memory memory will not be known until an effort is made to run a program, it may be impossible for the compiler, linker, or any other such tool to know if it will be adequate.  Nothing in the standard imposes any requirements upon what must happen if an attempt is made to run a program when insufficient memory is available to handle its stack requirements.

It would be helpful if the Standard provided a means by which a program could ensure some measure of predictable behavior when run with any amount of memory available, but at present it does not do so.  On many platforms, there will be some amount of available memory which will be large enough that the OS loader won't reject an executable, but will nonetheless be small enough that the application suffers a stack overflow almost immediately upon start-up.  The authors of the C standard didn't want to declare that C cannot be used with such platforms, but they also can't really say anything about what platforms will do when trying to run code with that critical amount of memory.